# not getting solution for error 500 whose root cause is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver

Tags: java, eclipse, vs-web-application-project

I am using eclipse photon and i am getting error 500, i have got some solution but not for my specific problem,that is-

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver

i dont understand how to remove java/sql/Driver type of error.

Here is my Error-

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

Message Servlet execution threw an exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.  

Exception



     javax.servlet.ServletException:      Servlet execution threw an exception


    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Root Cause      





java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver


    java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)


    java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)


    java.base/java.lang.System$2.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)


    java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$BootClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown Source)


    java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown Source)


    java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)


    java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)


org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1247)


org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)




     java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)


    java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)


    com.login.LoginCDao.getLoginC(LoginCDao.java:12)


    com.login.GetLogin.doGet(GetLogin.java:23)


`javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634`)


    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)


    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)



Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.


Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
```

Comment: Where's the error ..?

Comment: added..please check

Comment: You should probably also post the code that generated the error and include enough information to explain what the problem context is.

Comment: the error comes in the code where i have connected the database and it comes to all my projects connected to the DB

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have driver jar set in classpath properly. For instance mysql-connector in case you are using mysql.

In case of oracle, Download the appropriate ojdbc6.jar JDBC driver file for your database version [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html)

Comment: i am using oracle DB so which jar i need to set and how to set?

Comment: Since you are using web server to run this app, make sure jar is present in server libraries too. For instance incase of tomat, it should be located under tomcat_home/lib

Comment: Same was working fine before and i dont know from where this error start coming